# C++: ptr_container comparison

Tags: c++, boost, comparison

How can I customize the comparison of elements in a ptr_container? Using a ptr_set, I would like to define a function that checks for equality of elements. However, defining

```
bool operator==(const Foo& other) (or a friend function)
```

does not work. It just won't be invoked, although boost's unordered containers, on the other side, are aware of overloaded operator==s. Predicates a la:

```
struct FooEq
{
    bool operator()(const Foo& foo1, const Foo& foo2) const
};
```

don't work either and I cannot find a reference that describes how to accomplish this.

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int i, int j) : _i(i), _j(j) {}

    bool operator<(const Foo& other) const { return this->_i < other._i; }

    bool operator==(const Foo& other) const
    {
        std::cout << "== involed";

        return this->_j == other._j;
    }

    int _i;
    int _j;
};

boost::ptr_set<Foo> foos;
std::cout << foos.size() << "\n";
foos.insert(new Foo(1, 2));
std::cout << foos.size() << "\n";
foos.insert(new Foo(2, 2));
std::cout << foos.size() << "\n";
```

The foos are supposed to be equal since for both j == 2 holds.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry that's not clear. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to define a camparison operator so that set will work?

Comment: Yes, to ensure that there are no duplicate elements in the set.

Comment: @JoshD: edited. The ptr_set should only contain one foo, however it contains both. Moreover, operator== won't be invoked, the test output never appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set uses the < operator to insert items and test for equivalence (which is not quite the same as equality). This operator must define a strict weak ordering. Set will not use the == operator.

Quoted from the description for set:

> Compare: Comparison class: A class
>   that takes two arguments of the same
>   type as the container elements and
>   returns a bool. The expression
>   comp(a,b), where comp is an object of
>   this comparison class and a and b are
>   elements of the container, shall
>   return true if a is to be placed at an
>   earlier position than b in a strict
>   weak ordering operation. This can
>   either be a class implementing a
>   function call operator or a pointer to
>   a function (see constructor for an
>   example). This defaults to less,
>   which returns the same as applying the
>   less-than operator (a

If you elaborated what you are trying to accomplish, I could offer suggestions for a better container.

Comment: But why has ptr_set a template parameter 'compare' then?

Comment: @jena: that parameter is used to specify the < operator. If none is provided it defaults to the < operator.

Comment: @jena: if the answer was helpful for you, you can vote it up. I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your situation exactly. However, You can use std::set . It doesn't support duplication.

```
set<shared_ptr<T>>
```

is really helpful in your case.

Comment: I did that before and decided to use ptr_set to hide the pointers (the interace allows access the elements of the container). So I could either ignore that and go back to using std::set or explicitly check whether a given element is already in the ptr_container.  Hm